# Compare multiple sets of cells in Excel

Tags: excel, duplicates, countif

I'm looking to find unique names by comparing lists of names in different sheets in Excel. The first names and last names are in separate columns. I want to check if the full name is unique.

I cannot edit the cells with the names but I can edit the columns after the data.

i.e. *Sara Walker* and *Sam Walker* are different people.

I've gotten just the last names working using:

```
IF(COUNTIF(Sheet1!$B:$B,B3)=0,"none", "")
```

...and I've attempted to get both using:

```
IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!$B:$B, B3)+COUNTIF(Sheet2!$A:$A),"none", "")
```

...but:

1. when I add the `=0` it breaks
2. it gives me individually if there are duplicate last names and duplicate first names

Basically I want to check for duplicate last names and then check if the first names are different.

Comment: EDIT: the second formula should be IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!$B:$B, $B2)+COUNTIF(Sheet2!$A:$A, $A2),"none", "")

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that technique will give you what you need since it is counting items individually and you want to see if the combination has a count rather than if each has a count.

Try this:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A:A,A3,Sheet1!B:B,B3)=0,"Unique","Duplicate")
```

This will tell you if the name in A3:B3 of the current sheet (assuming the current sheet is not Sheet1) is already found in Sheet1 with the first name in Column A and the last name in Column B in a single row.

I modelled it after your Sheet1 formula assuming the first name is in A3 and the last name is in B3.  I am not sure if Sheet1 contains both names or if they are only found in Sheet2 based on what was posted.

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly! Also thanks to anyone who edited the question formatting, it makes a huge difference.